# Copy Excel Table Paste to Specific PPT Slide

Tags: excel, vba, macos, powerpoint

Details:
Mac Excel (2016) copying to Mac PPT (2016)

Eventually, I would like to loop through all tables and paste each table on its own individual slide in PPT.

But first I'm trying to simply copy one table from Excel and paste to a Specific PPT File (not a net new presentation).

```
Sub OpenPPTandCopySelectedTable()

Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application   
Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
PPT.Visible = True

'Open the specific Template
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="/Users/MyNameHere/Downloads/FileName.pptx"

'Make Specific File the Active Presentation
Set PPPres = PPT.ActivePresentation

'Copy the Excel Table
Range("Table1[#All]").Copy

'Select PowerPoint Slide number 2
PPT.Slides(2).Select

'Paste Special 
Application.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPastePNG

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, please add OPTION EXPLICIT to the first line in your code module. Make it a habit, and you'll be much happier in life. Second, your PasteSpecial line uses "Application", which will be Excel, but I think you want it to be the PowerPoint application. Use PPT.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial...

Comment: ^^ Also, I don't use Powerpoint VBA often (i.e. never), but should `PPT.Slides(2).Select` be `PPPres.Slides(2).Select`?  I would expect that `Slides` would be a property of a presentation, not of a Powerpoint application.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below (without using `Select` and `ActivePresentation`, which slows down the run-time of your code).

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenPPTandCopySelectedTable()

Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim myShape As Object

Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application

' Open the specific Template and set it (in 1 line)
Set PPPres = PPT.Presentations.Open(Filename:="/Users/MyNameHere/Downloads/FileName.pptx", ReadOnly:=msoFalse)

'Copy the Excel Table
Range("Table1[#All]").Copy

' Paste to PowerPoint and set to MyShape
'Set myShape = PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG, msoFalse)
' if you want to edit the properties
'With myShape
    '.Left = 
    '.Top =    
'End With

' Option 2: 
PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPastePNG)

End Sub
```

Comment: Received a Compile error: Method or data member not found. It is highlighting the ".PasteSpecial" in the `Set myShape = PPPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG, msoFalse)` line of code.

Comment: @BenSimmons when did you update it's for MAC ? I can't test it on MAC,since I am working on a PC. I've added asecond option, see it maybe it works for you

Comment: I had it in the original description. This looks to be the issue. the `PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)` seems to be the issue. Not sure how to accomplish is MAC PPT. Receive the same error as before.

Comment: @BenSimmons try `PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)` or `PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)` , let me know if they work for you

Comment: Same Compile Error with both the above. I've searched StackOverflow and other blogs- can't find anything specific to this MAC Excel to MAC PPT code.